# Extracting data from URL encoded String in HTML5

Tags: javascript, string, html, cordova, qr-code

I have QR code app. Data is stored in URL encoded format  like employee://id=&firstName=&lastName=
in the QR-code

I want to extract the data stored in the string. How can I do it in HTML5.
I am able to extract string from QR-code.

Comment: cant u just use string split to get all info?

Comment: the data would be b/w "KEY=" and "&". Can you let me know how to extract this using .match for regex ?

Comment: Typically you split on & to get the name/value pairs, then split on "=" for each to get the name and the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var data = "employee://id=12&firstName=james&lastName=joseph";

var employee = {};
data.replace(/(\w*=\w*)/g, function(a, b){ 
    var prop = a.split("=");
    employee[prop[0]] = prop[1];
});
```

now `employee.id` gives **12**, `employee.firstName` gives **james**, `employee.lastName` gives **joseph**

Answer (score 0):

see these links first
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp

then from your string  employee://id=123&firstName=abhi&lastName=singh
we can see that if u first split by // you would get

```
employee: 
id=123&firstName=abhi&lastName=singh  

discard the first one and again split using &. u'll get--

id=123
lastName=singh  
firstName=abhi
```

u can see the pattern :)